# Creating 2D array of doubles in c# on the fly with variable dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, t-sql, double

I have a number of very large matrices (sometimes of doubles, but perhaps other types) that can be of varying dimensions. I would like to store an entire array as varbinary(max)

I am able to store the record just fine (I think).  However, when I come to read the data, I don't know how to create a c# array with variable dimensions.

The SQL table looks like this:

```
create table test_varbinary_table(
    name varchar(256) null,
    vb_data varbinary(max) null
)
```

The stored procedure to write the data is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData 
    @name varchar(256),
    @data varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO test_varbinary_table (name, vb_data) VALUES (@name, @data);
END
```

The C# is here:

```
   double[,]  dblArySampleData = new double[2,3]  { {7.0, 3.0, 1.3 }, {8.333, 4.1211, 8.999 } };
    var result = new byte[6 * sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(dblArySampleData, 0, result, 0, result.Length);

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.insertData", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "foo");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", result);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        textBox1.Text = "No Failure!";
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
```

So now, I want to read the dang thing, but I don't know how to read it. Not even sure how to get started.  I could store the dimensions with the table, so that's two new fields, say, 'rows' and 'cols.'

But I need to be able to create a byte[] array of a length I don't know ... I guess I could query the rows and cols first and then compute length ... that seems obtuse, but doable.  But even if I get the byte[] array, I want to reconstruct a 2dim matrix.

Intuitively, I want to write:

```
double[,] dblArySampleData = new double[rows, cols];
```

but c# doesn't seem to like when the dimensions can't be variables.

Comment: "but c# doesn't seem to like when the dimensions can't be variables" > Why not? An error message perhaps? It would be very useful if you'd share that error message.

Comment: I retyped it and it worked.  Not sure what I messed up the last few times.